# Enable Ubuntu app for Cordova

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I'm just trying to create Ubuntu cordova project.
As I can see in the manual I should
Import Cordova assets into your HTML5 app project source. Do this from the SDK with: Tools >  Ubuntu > Add Cordova runtime to HTML5 project. 
But I just can't find Tools in the SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling an HTML5 app for Cordova probably requires you to run the latest version of Ubuntu (14.04).

Open the SDK and select an HTML5 project:

[image]

Then go as suggested by the documentation to Tools > Ubuntu > Add Cordova runtime to HTML5 project:

[image]